# ASP.NET Core: Couldn't build the project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am using asp.net core rc2 for my project. And this is the first project I am trying to build with .net core rc2 using the ef core rc2 final.  My project structure is as below:

[image]

It was working all fine. I even performed a migration once .. Now I added 3 more classes to the Models folder and the problem arises while building the project.

[image]

Despite of errors, if I try to run the project, I get this error:

[image]

First error shows nothing. If I click on the second error, this is what it displays:

[image]

There is also warning, but it doesn't hinder the running of the aplication.

**Update::**
Ok, What I did was:: I mis-spelled the EmpEnroll.Infrastructure project. This was referenced in the EmpEnroll. So without removing the reference, I deleted the class library project. So I believe this is the major cause. Now how do I resolve this error?

Plese let me know what am I missing or the possible solutions.